# Getting Pixel coordinates of a contour from the overall image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So I would like to get the XY coordinates of the center of a contour on an image. How would I go about this?

I have the contours defined and the objects detected now how do I get the pixel XY of the center.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Yes I did! Thanks. @SneakyPolarBear

Comment: If you used one of the answers here, please accept it or if you solved it another way, post your answer and accept that so that this question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the normal vectors at the start and end of the contour and calculate their intersection.

^ is for a simple 3 point contour ie a circular arc.  If you have more points, "center" is a kinda ambiguous term, but if you averaged all points contributing to the contour it could give you a center of mass which may be what you are after.

You could also get bounding boxes or circle etc as [described here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

You could also use the moments to get center of mass if you prefer as seen on the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d23/classcv_1_1Moments.html#details):

[image]

Comment: Can I use the moments? they are rectangular objects. Or can I not pull the XY data out of the return value out of cv2.moments?

Comment: @JordanTaranto [Yes, you can use moments.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: Is this giving me pixel coordinates? or what unit is this giving me?